# Google email extraction script - Exceeded maximum execution time (No matter what)

Tags: javascript, timeout, gmail

I am using the below script to extract email addresses from gmail based upon some search criteria and output them to a google spreadsheet. Functionally, the script works and does what I want it do.

However, I am constantly getting "Exceeded maximum execution time" when I run the script as the maximum execution time for gmail scripts appears to be five minutes. I have tested this with a smaller label in gmail with a handful of emails and the script runs successfully and outputs emails as expected. However when I attempt to extract anything in larger batches with more emails the script cannot finish.

This script is cobled from other stuff I found on the web. I have attempted to amend this time out issue by adding for loops in a try block with the exception being caught and sent to sleep so that the script could pause execution and not exceed the time limit, however this did not work. I have also tried other methods of sending the script to sleep to prevent time out from occuring but these where unsccessful.

Could someone help me in preventing the time out from occurring or else use some more efficient way of searching through email threads to grab the emails out?

Edit: I have amended the code with the suggestions added, however it still cannot complete without reaching execution time limit. Any ideas why the script is not pausing? I have also attempted to search just one message using GmailApp.search(search, 0, 1) however the script will not complete when I search my Inbox.

```
function extractEmailAddresses() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var userInputSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var labelName = userInputSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var keyword = userInputSheet.getRange("C2").getValue();

  var sheetName = "Label: " + labelName;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName (sheetName) || ss.insertSheet (sheetName, ss.getSheets().length);
  sheet.clear();

  var messageData = [];

  var search = "label:" + label + "is:unread " + keyword;

  // Process 50 Gmail threads in a batch to prevent script execution errors
  var threads = GmailApp.search(search, 1, 1);      

  var messages, from, email, subject, mailDate;

  try {

    for (var x=0; x<threads.length; x++) {

      var message = threads[x].getMessages()[0]; //Get message for thread
      from = message.getFrom();
      mailDate = message.getDate();
      from = from.match(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/g);   

      if ( from.length ) {            

        email = from[0];
        email = email.replace(">", "");
        email = email.replace("<", "");       

        //push emails to array
        messageData.push ([email, mailDate]);
      }
    }
  }

  catch (e) {
    //Pause script to prevent exceeded timeout error
    Logger.log(e.toString());
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
  }

  //Adding our emails to the spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange (1, 1, messageData.length, 2).setValues (messageData);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two quick ideas, I've not looked at it in detail and don't know the API well:

1. Don't call `getMessages` twice:

   Replace:

   ```
   from = threads[x].getMessages()[0].getFrom();
   mailDate = threads[x].getMessages()[0].getDate();
   ```

   with:

   ```
   var message = threads[x].getMessages()[0];
   from = message.getFrom();
   mailDate = message.getDate();
   ```
2. Avoid using `setValue` on each iteration: Single cell updates to the spreadsheet will be slow, as each time will involve communicating with Sheets infrastructure and committing a value. Instead, build up a bigger array of cell values to change and set it all at once using `setValues(Object[][])`

Those are just thoughts from a quick glance, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have amended the script accordingly, however the script still cannot complete in a normal time frame.

Comment: I suggest you step through with a debugger or do some timings to work out where the time is being taken. e.g. How long does the call `var threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 50);` take? Is that the majority? Or is it in fact taken up mainly in looping through the results? Profiling your script to identify where the time is taken will allow you identify where to focus on for improvements.

Comment: It appears to be `var threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 50);` that may be taking the most time, as I changed it to `var threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 5);` to look through fewer threads but it is is still unable to complete in time as it searching the Inbox. Is this because the Inbox is too large? It works when I try searching a label with fewer emails, but I need it to work with a larger data set too. I will try the debugging as you suggested, thanks.